# Сочетание отвлеченных И.С. с неопределенно-количественными словами

Tags: морфология

Могут ли отвлеченные имена существительные, имеющие форму только единственного числа, сочетаться с неопределенно-количественными словами (мало, много, несколько...) в форме Р.п. мн.ч.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Отвлечённые существительные** обозначают различные абстрактные понятия, качества, действия, состояния в отвлечении от носителя признака и производителя действия:
красота, ловкость, храбрость, развитие, энтузиазм, слякоть, белизна, холод, тепло, сострадание, проводы.

**Некоторые** отвлечённые существительные могут сочетаться со словами *много/мало* (стоят при этом в форме **единственного числа**): много внимания, немного радости, немало горя.

В форме Р. п. мн. числа может быть только существительное множественного числа:
*Случай этот недавний и доставил мне **много хлопот*** (Ф. М. Достоевский).

Вот, думаю, самое известное:
*И вот она, нарядная,

На праздник к нам пришла

**И много, много радости*** [не радостей!]
*Детишкам принесла.*
Р. Кудашева

[Отвлеченные (абстрактные) имена существительные](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/sushhestvitelnoe/otvlechennye-abstraktnye-imena-suschestvitelnye.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если, как вы утверждаете, слово имеет только форму единственного числа, то из этого однозначно следует, что формы родительного падежа множественного числа у него быть не может.

Другое дело, что некоторые отвлеченные существительные могут образовывать множественное число, изменяя свою семантику. Они при этом перестают быть отвлеченными.

> *Красота* (ощущение прекрасного) - только ед., отвлеченное. *Красоты* (красивые места) - только мн., собирательное. Его поэма «Карелия» заключает в себе много красот (Белинский)
>
> *Чтение* (процесс восприятия текста) - только ед., отвлеченное. *Чтение* (рассмотрение документа в парламенте) - ед. и мн., конкретное. Этот законопроект прошел много чтений.